nav2 navigation not driving to goal pose
I have a custom differential robot and trying to get nav2 navigation to work, but after giving a goal pose the robot just random drives a short distance in random direction twist around a bit and then stops.
I have a map made and saved with slam toolbox and load this into nav2 localization. The map I see in rviz2 lines up good with the lidar points. When I drive around manual using teleop keyboard the map keeps tracked good with the lidar points. Also the cost maps display correctly and have no weird behavior in them.
When I then give a goal pose, seeing in the cost map that the full route is clear, the robot in general turns around to a wrong direction drives a bit, turns around some more drives into a wall and then gives up and aborts.
In the terminal were I start nav2 navigation I can see the following output. (I had to cut out allot to make it fit in this post, I removed all repeating messages and most of the start up and shut down)
[lifecycle_manager-8] [INFO] [1727722306.846965445] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Activating behavior_server
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722306.851251933] [behavior_server]: Activating
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722306.851782862] [behavior_server]: Activating spin
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722306.852113273] [behavior_server]: Activating backup
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722306.852285301] [behavior_server]: Activating drive_on_heading
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722306.852465767] [behavior_server]: Activating assisted_teleop
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722306.852631232] [behavior_server]: Activating wait
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722306.853038829] [behavior_server]: Creating bond (behavior_server) to lifecycle manager.
[lifecycle_manager-8] [INFO] [1727722307.822672198] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Server behavior_server connected with bond.
[lifecycle_manager-8] [INFO] [1727722307.823050108] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Activating bt_navigator
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1727722307.830348628] [bt_navigator]: Activating
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1727722317.697826688] [bt_navigator]: Creating bond (bt_navigator) to lifecycle manager.
[lifecycle_manager-8] [ERROR] [1727722320.563364839] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Server bt_navigator was unable to be reached after 4.00s by bond. This server may be misconfigured.
[lifecycle_manager-8] [ERROR] [1727722320.564043838] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Failed to bring up all requested nodes. Aborting bringup.
[lifecycle_manager-8] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'statemap::TransitionUndefinedException'
[lifecycle_manager-8]   what():  no such transition in current state
[ERROR] [lifecycle_manager-8]: process has died [pid 2268, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/nav2_lifecycle_manager/lifecycle_manager --ros-args --log-level info --ros-args -r __node:=lifecycle_manager_navigation --params-file /tmp/launch_params_9rwt5ttb --params-file /tmp/launch_params_np9_8sko --params-file /tmp/launch_params_t61issk6'].
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1727722352.930484600] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location (2.65, -0.41) to (1.82, 0.25)
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722352.960594598] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.023772147] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for follow_path
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.037486596] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1727722353.022573210] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1727722353.026382987] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722353.030208077] [controller_server]: No goal checker was specified in parameter 'current_goal_checker'. Server will use only plugin loaded general_goal_checker . This warning will appear once.
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.046145508] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Node timed out while executing service call to local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1727722353.048278544] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.059619910] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.068210073] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Node timed out while executing service call to local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap.
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.101981987] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.110640899] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for spin
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.127759977] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.137551890] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for wait
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.150459947] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.160193788] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for backup
[bt_navigator-5] [ERROR] [1727722353.171131411] [bt_navigator]: Goal failed
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722353.171575830] [bt_navigator]: [navigate_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722353.284164604] [behavior_server]: Running backup
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722353.306245002] [behavior_server]: Running spin
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722353.314291008] [behavior_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin behavior.
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722353.419960214] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1727722355.861203807] [tf_help]: Transform data too old when converting from odom to map
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1727722355.861594374] [tf_help]: Data time: 1727722355s 611168514ns, Transform time: 1727722355s 23394683ns
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722355.874022231] [controller_server]: Unable to transform robot pose into global plan's frame
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722356.202684492] [controller_server]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722357.516157514] [behavior_server]: spin completed successfully
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722358.258283115] [behavior_server]: wait completed successfully
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722359.097885461] [behavior_server]: Collision Ahead - Exiting DriveOnHeading
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722359.098208841] [behavior_server]: backup failed
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722359.098394619] [behavior_server]: [backup] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1727722431.967878627] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location (2.77, -0.18) to (2.89, -0.87)
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1727722432.139951168] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722432.231678732] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722432.257668545] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.105136498] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for compute_path_to_pose
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.144422567] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Node timed out while executing service call to global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap.
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722433.157881633] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[bt_navigator-5] [ERROR] [1727722433.202116742] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Failed to cancel action server for follow_path
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1727722433.225551178] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1727722433.235906645] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[bt_navigator-5] [ERROR] [1727722433.231941081] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Failed to get result for follow_path in node halt!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.252638735] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1727722433.258113235] [controller_server]: Goal was canceled. Stopping the robot.
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722433.258427449] [controller_server]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Client requested to cancel the goal. Cancelling.
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.370396268] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[planner_server-3] [INFO] [1727722433.377410068] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the global_costmap
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.396651911] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Node timed out while executing service call to global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722433.421609448] [behavior_server]: Running spin
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722433.425181060] [behavior_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin behavior.
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.618407342] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.618756504] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for spin
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.704041614] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.727169387] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for wait
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.801587371] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.803236616] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for backup
[bt_navigator-5] [ERROR] [1727722433.820941243] [bt_navigator]: Goal failed
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722433.821785761] [bt_navigator]: [navigate_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722433.855583112] [behavior_server]: Running backup
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722433.857981774] [behavior_server]: Running wait
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722438.229133565] [behavior_server]: spin completed successfully
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722438.859149823] [behavior_server]: wait completed successfully
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722439.067819099] [behavior_server]: Collision Ahead - Exiting DriveOnHeading
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722439.068179771] [behavior_server]: backup failed
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722439.068380653] [behavior_server]: [backup] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[bt_navigator-5] [INFO] [1727722445.746601859] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location (2.61, -0.04) to (2.85, -0.91)
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722445.800252866] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1727722445.819135236] [controller_server]: Received a goal, begin computing control effort.
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722445.824708953] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722445.830402148] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for follow_path
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1727722445.834357244] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722445.852625039] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722445.861581830] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Node timed out while executing service call to local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap.
[controller_server-1] [INFO] [1727722445.942305551] [local_costmap.local_costmap]: Received request to clear entirely the local_costmap
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722445.947802655] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722446.001981988] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722446.002322712] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for spin
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722446.044503477] [behavior_server]: Running spin
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722446.045642887] [behavior_server]: Turning 1.57 for spin behavior.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722446.121095282] [behavior_server]: Running wait
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722446.079885856] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722446.080867299] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for wait
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722446.141600126] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722446.151451695] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: Timed out while waiting for action server to acknowledge goal request for backup
[bt_navigator-5] [ERROR] [1727722446.162084659] [bt_navigator]: Goal failed
[bt_navigator-5] [WARN] [1727722446.162455851] [bt_navigator]: [navigate_to_pose] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722446.269131990] [behavior_server]: Running backup
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722447.698308289] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1727722447.736101620] [tf_help]: Transform data too old when converting from odom to map
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1727722447.742447045] [tf_help]: Data time: 1727722447s 120656391ns, Transform time: 1727722446s 860252684ns
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722447.752005181] [controller_server]: Unable to transform robot pose into global plan's frame
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722450.279506192] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 20.0000Hz
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1727722450.281385799] [tf_help]: Transform data too old when converting from odom to map
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1727722450.281560223] [tf_help]: Data time: 1727722449s 360944008ns, Transform time: 1727722449s 7866604ns
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722450.281977457] [controller_server]: Unable to transform robot pose into global plan's frame
[controller_server-1] [ERROR] [1727722450.584528535] [controller_server]: Controller patience exceeded
[controller_server-1] [WARN] [1727722450.585168317] [controller_server]: [follow_path] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [INFO] [1727722451.122977330] [behavior_server]: wait completed successfully
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722456.047173946] [behavior_server]: Exceeded time allowance before reaching the Spin goal - Exiting Spin
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722456.048402208] [behavior_server]: spin failed
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722456.048660746] [behavior_server]: [spin] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722456.270993252] [behavior_server]: Exceeded time allowance before reaching the DriveOnHeading goal - Exiting DriveOnHeading
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722456.271304601] [behavior_server]: backup failed
[behavior_server-4] [WARN] [1727722456.271494494] [behavior_server]: [backup] [ActionServer] Aborting handle.

I have been unsuccessful finding the error causing the unwanted behavior, at this point I haven't concluded if the error lies in the nav2 setting or maybe somewhere else.
Below the parameters I use for nav2.
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.02
    update_min_d: 0.025
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
    - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
    - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node

bt_navigator_navigate_through_poses_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] # "precise_goal_checker"
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    # Goal checker parameters
    #precise_goal_checker:
    #  plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
    #  xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    #  stateful: True
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
    # DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 1.0
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 1.0
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      # Add high threshold velocity for turtlebot 3 issue.
      # https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/issues/75
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.14
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 2.0
        inflation_radius: 0.1
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      robot_radius: 0.14
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 2.0
        inflation_radius: 0.1
      always_send_full_costmap: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    # Overridden in launch by the "map" launch configuration or provided default value.
    # To use in yaml, remove the default "map" value in the tb3_simulation_launch.py file & provide full path to map below.
    yaml_filename: "/home/pi3/ros2_ws/my_map.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: False
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: false
      allow_unknown: true

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    use_sim_time: False
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [1.0, 0.0, 1.0]
    min_velocity: [-1.0, 0.0, -1.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

Thanks in advance. If you need any more information just let me know and I will update the question.

This issue was due to local costmap parameters set to 3D this needed to be 2D.
